# Evaluating f(N,R) mod(m)

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, primes, mathematics

The goal is to find \$f(n,r)\mod(m)\$ for the given values of \$n\$, \$r\$, \$m\$, where \$m\$ is a prime number.

$$f(n,r) = \dfrac{F(n)}{F(n-r) \cdot F(r)}$$

where

$$F(n) = 1^1 \cdot 2^2 \cdot 3^3 \cdot \ldots  \cdot n^n$$

Here is the Python code snippet I've written:

```
    n_r = n - r 
    num = 1
    den = 1

    if n_r > r:
        for j in xrange(n_r + 1, n + 1): 
            num = num*(j**j)    
        for k in xrange(2, r + 1):
            den = den*(k**k)

        answer = num/den
        ans = answer%m
        print ans

    else:
        for j in xrange(r + 1, n + 1): 
            num = num*(j**j)    
        for k in xrange(2, n_r + 1):
            den = den*(k**k)

        answer = num/den
        ans = answer%m
        print ans
```

This code runs for small values of \$n\$ (when \$n <= 100\$). But for large values of \$n\$ ~ \$10^5\$, the code seems to be inefficient, exceeding the time limit of 2 sec. How can I generalize and optimize this computation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function is slow for large values of `n` because the intermediate
values of `num` and `den` quickly grow to huge integers, making the multiplication slow.

You can improve that
by reducing each intermediate result "modulo m", so that all numbers will
always be in the range `0 ... m-1`.

The final division `num/den` must then be computed as a "modular division":

```
def mod_div(a, b, m):
    """modular division

    Returns a solution c of a = b * c mod m, or None if no such number c exists.
    """
    g, x, y = egcd(b, m)
    if a % g == 0:
        return (a * (x // g)) % m
    else:
        return None
```

using the ["Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), for example with the code from
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Recursive_algorithm

```
def egcd(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return (b, 0, 1)
    else:
        g, y, x = egcd(b % a, a)
        return (g, x - (b // a) * y, y)
```

The `if/else` can be avoided, either as @Janos suggested, or by replacing
`r` by `n-r` if the latter is smaller. Your function would then look like this:

```
def f(n, r, m):

    if n - r < r:
        r = n - r

    num = 1
    den = 1

    for j in xrange(n - r + 1, n + 1): 
        num = (num * (j ** j % m)) % m
    for k in xrange(2, r + 1):
        den = (den * (k ** k % m)) % m

    return mod_div(num, den, m)
```

At least for large values of `n` this should be faster. I made a test
with `f(10000, 100, 747164718467)`:

- Your code: 25 seconds
- Above code: 0.2 seconds

A possible further improvement would be to compute the powers `j ** j % m` also
with a "modular power" method, such as `power_mod()` from http://userpages.umbc.edu/~rcampbel/Computers/Python/lib/numbthy.py.
The reduced the time for calculating `f(10000, 100, 747164718467)`
to 0.05 seconds on my computer.

Comment: The proposed code does not handle the "modular inverse does not exist" case. For example f(6,2,2) makes `den == 0`.

Comment: @JanneKarila: You are right. Actually the first step would be to prove that f(n,r) is an integer at all (which is implied in the question). I think that can be done similar as [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/11606/42969) for binomial coefficients. And then I think that if the denominator has the prime factor `m` then the numerator has at least the factor `m^2`, so the modulo result would be zero in that case.

Comment: @JanneKarila: I have updated the code so that it works for those cases as well.

Answer (score 1):

The logic in the two branches of the `if` statement is essentially the same,
the only difference is in the parameters of `xrange`.
You can generalize the logic using a variable `x`,
set to `max(n_r, r)`:

```
x = n_r if n_r > r else r

for j in range(x + 1, n + 1):
    num *= j ** j
for k in range(2, n - x + 1):
    denom *= k ** k

answer = num / denom
ans = answer % m
print(ans)
```

I made some other changes too:

- For compatibility with Python 3:

  - Use `print(...)` instead of `print ...`
  - Use `range` instead of `xrange`
- More generous spacing around operators, for [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- Use `p *= q` instead of `p = p * q`
- Renamed `den` to `denom`

As for the speed issue... That seems more of a math problem than Python,
and I don't know the answer for that.